# RE2: Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/re2' (npm)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, re2

Based on sonarQube recommendations I'm trying to replace my native regular expression with RE2. after installation it shows:

Error: Cannot find module './build/Release/re2'

NB: The project is managed by npm.

The regex checks if an email is correct in a login page built with react.

Answer (score 1):

try install it with `yarn add re2`